# What is the right way to extend twitter bootstrap regarding ul li background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have an own background image for a dropdown menu (that is done via unordered list and list items -> ul and li).

What is the adequate way to realize this with twitter bootstrap?

Code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
    <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
    <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
    <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <!--<button class="my-btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example-->
            <button class="my-btn my-btn-primary my-dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wanted to add an image across the full menu (`<ul>`) and not each list item (`<li>`).

Here's a Fiddle showing how it can be done: https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/c6dqeufr/

All I'm doing is applying a background image on the `<ul>` using CSS, like so:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background: url(http://www.adelepham.com/deepthoughts/gray-pattern.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```